# Adding cookie functionality to jQuery script (ensuring table cells remain highlighted)

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have the following jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var color = ['none', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];
        $('table').on('change','select', function() {
            $(this).parents('td').css('background', color[$(':selected', this).index()]);
        });​
    });
</script>
```

Which highlights all table cells on a row when an option in a select box is chosen. I have downloaded and implemented the jQuery cookie plugin. My Question is how can I implement functionality (additional code) so that the row of table cells will remain highlighted when the page is refreshed or when a user logs out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to store selected color in the cookie and then read it back. You can use [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). Sample usage here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($.cookie("yourname")) {
        // applying color from cookie
        var color = $.cookie("yourname");
        $('div').css('background', color);
        $('select').val(color);
    }

    $('div').on('change', 'select', function() {
        // applying selected color, storing it in the cookie
        var color = $(this).val();
        $.cookie("yourname", color);
        $('div').css('background', color);
    });

});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hFzVc/1/)

PS: For the demo I use slightly modified script, since you haven't provided your HTML markup.

Comment: Thank you, my HTML looks like this:                                     echo ' <select name="Select1">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>Approved</option>
                    <option>Pending</option>
                    <option>Dissaproved</option>
                </select>';
           echo "</td></tr>";                                         The table is populated by database results. I then mark an order as approved,pending or disapproved and the table cells change colour.

Comment: Thanks this works and the page state remains the same on refresh or when logged out. How would I target each row of the table? as currently the whole table is changing colour. Also would it be possible to put the CSS colours outside of each option name, as they will need to remain the same (approved, pending and dissaproved) sorry one final requirement would be so that the option value itself retains the same state on page refresh, individually. Many thanks

Comment: And does it make sense? You say you are displaying orders in different colors and you want to store the colors in a cookie.. Wouldn't it be better to store just user id or some token to be able to render the colors on server side?

Comment: Hi, yes it does, I was having difficulty selecting an individual row when the status is changed, and ensuring that the select box option value remains the same. This would probably be a better option. All i need to do is store the state of the page so that when a user returns they will see the correct statuses and colours. Could i do this using php? Thank you

Comment: also multiple users will be viewing the table

Comment: I see that your example works using a DIV. However this would need to be individual table rows which are populated by a database. Thanks

Comment: please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250374/processing-form-data-dynamically-populated-from-a-database

Comment: you will need to modify it according to your needs.. for table rows, you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hFzVc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for the answer. What would be the best way to implement it in the following code:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

{
echo '<tr>';

echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_no[]" value="' . $row['Orderno'] . '"/></td>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_date[]" value="' . $row['Orderdate'] . '"/>   </td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_ordered_by[]" value="' . $row['Orderedby'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_supplier[]" value="' . $row['Supplier'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_total_price[]" value="' . $row['totalprice'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="order_requested_by[]" value="' . $row['requestedby'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<select name="order_status[]">';
    echo '<option></option>';
    echo '<option>Approved</option>';
    echo '<option>Pending</option>';
    echo '<option>Dissaproved</option>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}
?>
```